# Windows Phone SilverLight 8.1 needs Push capability defines, but it does not?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I followed the excelent tutorial I found here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/nb-no/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-phone-get-started/#overview

Only problem, when I run this on my phone, WP 8.1, it complains that "ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION" is not define. Over at the manifest this capability is no where to be found as it was removed in 8.1 (default I guess).

So whats wrong? This is a fresh app, not one I've upgraded or something.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight, `ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION` can be found under `Capabilites` section on `WMAppManifest` file

[image]